# How can I configure options using the traceur module on nodejs

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, traceur

How do I configure options using the traceur module on nodejs. I'm doing the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
require('traceur').require.makeDefault(function(filename) {

    // don't transpile our dependencies, just our app
    return filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1;

});

traceur.options.annotations = true;

require('./start.js');
```

`traceur.options.annotations = true` is not resulting in annotations being enabled in traceur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the options as the second argument to makeDefault:

```
require('traceur').require.makeDefault(function(filename) {
    // don't transpile our dependencies, just our app
    return filename.indexOf('node_modules') === -1;
}, {annotations: true});
```

See https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/blob/master/src/node/require.js#L58

You need to update use this feature.

Comment: Thanks lots. Works as expected now.